# .table-responsive and scroll always visible

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I use ".table-responsive" class (Last version Bootstrap : 3.3.7) for my table, and Scroll always visible.

```
<div class="container container-main">
    <div class="table-responsive toggle-history">
        <table class="table table-extra-bordered table-hover table-striped">
            ...
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Example : https://jsfiddle.net/fL00nudz/2/

I want to hide scroll If they are not necessary. Can you help me ?

Answer (score 1):

So the row class and col-* classes are messing up your table because the row has negative margins. Try finding a different solution how to style your content inside without using them.

Comment: Thanks

    table tr td .row {
        margin-right: 0;
        margin-left: 0
    }

It's work true :)